# Difference between document.getElementById and window.ElementId?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have control that I render throw ajax and append it to div in the document:

```
function RevrievePopUpViaAjax(url) {
     if (document.getElementById('abcd') == null) {
         var jqxhr = $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: "GET"
         })
         .done(function (data) {
             $("#contentDiv").append(data);

         })
         .fail(function () {
             alert("error");
         })
     }
     else {
         abcd.PerformCallback();
     }
}
```

This is my original function in the first time I call it, it renders control with id 'abcd' when I call it the second time there is a difference between document.getElementById('abcd') that return null and shows like the element doesn't exists **although it is really do exist** to window.abcd that not return null and shows that the element do exists...

It probably my misunderstand of something...
someone can explain it to me?

Comment: Can you show exactly how you are using `document.getElementById('abcd')` vs `window.abcd` within your code? it's all about context/timing. And what the actual id is.

Comment: And if you're using jQuery, why are you even bothering with `document.getElementById()`? You can just use `$("#myID")`... Also, consider using `$.get(url, function(data){ ...})`.

Comment: @Luxelin I tried it and it is also not working...

Comment: @KevinB I will now update to my original code

Comment: the logic there doesn't make sense... Your first conditional tests to see if an element exists. If it doesn't exist, you're... using `abcd.PerformCallback()`... that's VERY confusing... What is `abcd.PerformCallback`?

Comment: why I am asking if it not exists...(document.getElementById('abcd') == null) then I render it with ajax and if it do exist I make callback...

Comment: I see. still. What is `adbc.PerformCallback`? are you really adding properties to dom elements? Why?

Comment: PerformCallback() is a function that abcd has...

Comment: well i can tell that much... but why does it exist? What do you mean by *"there is a difference between document.getElementById('abcd') to window.abcd"*? I don't quite understand what you are asking. It's unclear what the problem/mystery you are trying to solve is.

Comment: I edit it my question hope it is more clear now...

Comment: What does `console.log(abcd)` show you, and how are you defining `PerformCallback()`?